# Non atomic ring example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-representation

Can someone provide me with an example of a ring that is not atomic, that is, there is an element that has no finite factorization in irreducibles?

Comment: [DaRT query for nonatomic domains](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=124) There are 5 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \mathbb Q[ x, x^\frac12,x^\frac 1 3\ldots ]$, the ring of polynomials with fractional exponents. Now try factoring $x$ which is not a unit in $R$ because it’s inverse would have to have an exponent of negative degree.